# PIVOT function not working from SQLCMD

Tags: pivot, sqlcmd

PIVOT function not working from SQLCMD while exactly same query is running fine 
from SSMS
SQL server version 2008. while running from sqlcmd it is giving syntax error near PIVOT

I am putting the query in a .sql file and supplying that via -i option of sqlcmd. no

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY EMP-ID,Date order by EMP-ID ) AS rno,
      EMP-ID,Date, EMP-CAT 
  FROM DB.table1  
 where EMP-CAT  != 'XXX'

 ) as L
PIVOT
(
    MAX(EMP-CAT)
    FOR rno IN ("1","2","3")
)AS pvt1
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Server XXXXXXX\CCCCCCC, Line 16
Incorrect syntax near '1'.    Line 16 is the one line above ) as L   . This is running perfectly fine in SSMS

Comment: Is it the use of the double quotes?

Comment: no idea. since the query is running perfectly in SSMS.  I will try making single quote.  I have checked making the quote as single quote also but same issue